# how to make a switching color bar depending in the status of game.?

Tags: java, android

I am making a vertical progress bar  in  which the color bar will  be color green if the player completed or finish the game.if he/she not completed the game it will be color red.
[example](http://24.media.tumblr.com/50fa507a3bea1fa877f3d87cb9a75428/tumblr_mrs5mtecyR1qeomf8o1_500.jpg)
 how I make it in xml.?

```
enum(FOURPIX1LTR, FOURPIX1NBR, LTRMAZE, NBRMAZE);
image imgGameStatus = null; //
Loop through the games //

for (i = 0; i < numGames; i++) {

    switch (gameStatus[i]) {
    case "unfinished":

        imgGameStatus = imgGreyBox;

        break;

    case "gameover":
        imgGameStatus = imgRedBox;

        break;
    case "completed":
        imgGameStatus = imgGreenBox;

        break;
    }
}

// Take whatever imgGameStatus is and update indicator icon
ResultsPage.MazeIndicator.Image = imgGameStatus;
```

Comment: Why in XML? XML is static, you need to update the status dynamically roughly like your code looks

Comment: But how should I align  the text and the color bar.?